# Let B be any set and $g : B \rightarrow B$ be a function satisfying the condition $(g \circ g)(x) = x$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Let $g : B \rightarrow B$ be a function satisfying the condition $(g \circ g)(x) = x$
for all $x \in B$. Show that $g$ is a bijection.

For $g$ is onto
we want to prove that there exists an  $a \in B$ such that $g(a) = b$ for arbitrary element of $B$.

Let $b \in B$, then  since $(g \circ g)(b)=b$, then $ g(g(b))=b$.
There exists $a \in B$ , $ g(b)=a \in B$ so that $g(g(b))=g(a)=b$ as required.

Hence $g$ is onto.

How we want to prove that there exists $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ for $x_1,x_2 \in B$,  where $x_1=x_2$. 
 
Let $x_1,x_2 \in B$ and  suppose $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ , so $g(g(x_1))=g(g(x_2)) $.

Then since $g \circ g(x)=x$ and $x$ is in $B$, $x_1=x_2$, hence $g$ is one to one.

Is this right? Or is there better way to prove this?

Comment: The identity $(g \circ g)(x) = x$ for all $x \in B$ means that $g$ fulfils the definition of $g^{-1}$. Since $g$ is invertible, it is a bijection.

Comment: Your work is perfectly nice, each step is quite clear except when you write "we want to prove that *there exist* $g(x1)=g(x2)$ (...)" when you clearly mean (and you did prove it) "we want to prove that **for all** $x1,x2\in B$ (...)".